# Streaming a json element

Tags: java, json, hadoop, inputstream

Let's say I have a json that looks like this:

```
{"body":"abcdef","field":"fgh"}
```

Now suppose the value of the 'body' element is huge(~100 MB or more). I would like to stream out the value of the body element instead of storing it in a String.
How can I do this? Is there any Java library I could use for this?

This is the line of code that fails with an OutOfMemoryException when a large json value comes in:

```
String inputStreamString = (String) JsonPath.read(textValue.toString(), "$.body");
```

'textValue' here is a hadoop.io.Text object.
I'm assuming that the OutOfMemory error occurs because we try to do method calls like toString() (which creates a new object), and JsonPath.read(), all of which are done in-memory. I need to know if there is an approach I could take while handling large-sized textValue objects.
Please let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: When you say "I have a json", do you talk about a file in your file system?

Comment: What do you mean "stream out". Your question is incredibly unclear.

Comment: Yes, in this case the json file can be assumed to be in the file system. 
And when I say 'stream out', I mean to say I would like to do something like JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$.body") and instead of getting a String value in return, I would like to get an InputStream .

Answer (score 3):

[JsonSurfer](https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer) is good for processing very large JSON data with selective extraction.

Example how to surf in JSON data collecting matched values in the listeners:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jsonFile));
JsonSurfer surfer = new JsonSurfer(GsonParser.INSTANCE, GsonProvider.INSTANCE);
SurfingConfiguration config = surfer.configBuilder().bind("$.store.book[*]", new JsonPathListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValue(Object value, ParsingContext context) throws Exception {
            JsonObject book = (JsonObject) value;
        }
    }).build();
surfer.surf(reader, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) offers a streaming API for [generating and processing JSON](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example) data.

Comment: My understanding is that libraries like Jackson are useful when you have huge json files, but the values of the individual json elements are small so that they can be stored in Java objects without blowing the JVM memory.
But in my case, I have a few json elements but the values stored in them are huge, leading to OutOfMemory exceptions.

Comment: So you've got one single JSON attribute with huge value?